# Reading JPEG from Android Internal Storage

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-internal-storage

I have this code:

```
String imgPath = context.getFilesDir() + Constants.FILE_PATH + File.separator + customizer.getWallpaperPath();
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
helpdeskLogo.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

But, I find correctly the path, go to line for 'decodeFile', but when I arrived at the line to set the image on 'helpdesklogo', the bmp value was null. I'm trying a lot of hour with many solutions, my ideas were ended!

**EDIT** (*...and solved*):

I found the problem! I'm execute that code before setting content view, I'm leaving this question for each people having my same error.

Thanks to all guys!

Comment: check if file exists or not , possibly you are receiving incorrect path 

File imageFile= new  File(imgPath );
if(imageFile.exists()){
    Bitmap mBitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
    helpdeskLogo.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}

Answer (score 0):

include this permission in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```